# Is it bad practice to import a file from inside itself?

Tags: python, import, module

Essentially, I have a program that will run forever until my user suggests that they wish to leave, at which point it terminates.

Example Code: (example.py)

```
print("This is an example!")
if input("Want to leave?") != "No":
    import example
```

Of course, my code is much more complicated than this, but this demonstrates the purpose.

I know I could use a 'while' loop with a condition but personally speaking, this method looks neater (but I don't know if it's `python`ic).

**My question: What are the downsides of this? Is this discouraged or good practice?**

Reasons for downsides would be appreciated :)

Comment: Modules are only imported once and then cached. So don't be surprised if it does not work as intended.

Comment: `import` is not "run this file".

Comment: Even if this did work (which, as others have pointed out, is *very* unlikely), this is the kind of non-standard, "clever" control flow that makes reading and understanding code impossible.

Comment: @user2357112 I know :) But `python` automatically runs any modules when they're being imported, which is what I'm taking advantage of here.

Comment: @Adi219: No, Python runs a module's code to *initialize* the module, which doesn't happen on every import.

Comment: @user2357112 If I used `importlib.reload()`, wouldn't it work?

Answer (score -1):

I don't think its good idea, in python modules used to connect your code and allow you link and reuse code easily.

First of all, I think this method of "looping" is not efficient since loading python module is heavier operation than simply jumping to a new line in the code.

Some more practical downsides I can think about is when you will insert another code into your module (as you said your code is much more complicated). In general, my ideology is that not everything you can do you should do. Like you can use `while` loop iterating on a list, or iterate using indexes instead of iterators:

```
for i in range(len(arr)):
    print(arr[i])
```

but of course, it is not "pythonic" (and also it is not efficient).